# How do you control callbacks and stop them from returning without using async?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, callback, control-flow

So I'm working on a project using Node and Angular (first project). Basically I want to get some content out of the database using Angulars $http service which calls an endpoint thats setup in Express that queries the database using Sequelize. Here's a snippet of each:

**Frontend App.js**

```
$http
    .get('/getmessages').success(function(data){
    $scope.messages = data;
    })
```

**Serverside messages controller**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    model.getMessages(function(results){
        return results;
    });
})
```

**Model**

```
exports.getMessages = function(callback){
  var result = model.findAll().then(function(messages){
  return callback(messages);
});
```

So the problem I am faced with is that the code is returning to quick before the model has had a chance to return and I need to control this. Do I really need to use async for my particular problem? I've been researching how to control the flow but I can't get an answer for what I need. Thanks in advance if you can take a look.

Comment: There's a lot of returning, but to where? Do you have a `res.send` anywhere or somewhere the content is outputted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine your callbacks.

```
function(req, res, next){
  model.getMessages(function(results){
    return results;
}
```

Your serverside code will return undefined. It will run  `model.getMessages`...and while that is happening, since there is nothing left to do, just return out. That's why it looks like it's happening too quickly.

Might want to `res.send` back inside a callback, after your model returns.

Thoughts on Async in the comments.

Comment: ...btw, async is not completely necessary, but I recommend trying to figure it out as that is one of the benefits of working in Angular, and it looks like you're working on a project to learn about it.

Comment: Thank you! I was missing res.send. I guess by returning doesn't actually send an HTTP response back to the client like you can do with PHP and AJAX. Thanks again

Comment: No problem! You did a good job of wording where you were stuck, including useful snippets from app, server, and model.